# What are the best tools or ways to interact with a smart contract from a word-press website?

Tags: solidity, metamask, contract-invocation, dapps, php

I am currently working on a WordPress website and I want to interact with a deployed smart contract and need help selecting the right tools or ways to interact.

Answer (score 1):

Smart contracts are interacted with frontend JavaScript, regardless of what other technologies you are using.

See: [Web3.js](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/), [Ethers.js](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/)

Comment: I understand that,  sometimes i may need to call the smart contracts from the backend, that way i would go with web3.php. wanted to know if there are wordpress plugins to make interaction with metamask and smart contracts easier. Thanks.